# Time in a cosmological model

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, coordinate-systems, time, space-expansion

In a cosmological model usually we set that $g_{00}$ is only a function of $x_0$ because we want that each steady experimentator measure the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is, but we usually define the time coordinate as for an observer travelling along the Hubble flow, i.e. isotropic with respect to the expansion of the universe. Then in something like the Friedmann metric we have $g_{00} =1$ (assuming a trivial lapse function).

**Edit (more detail):**  
*I'm not sure this answers your question still, but I thought I'd include more detail*: 
To be more technical, all we need is for the spacetime manifold to be globally hyperbolic (i.e. foliated by 3-manifold hypersurfaces) in order to define a global *t*. But in cosmology we already have much more: we assume the cosmological principle, which means spacetime can be foliated into spacelike hypersurfaces which are also spherically symmetric about each point. This (along with Weyl's Postulate, which demands the matter geodesics are orthogonal to the spacelike hypersurfaces at $t$), gives us the orthogonal structure we need to write
$$ ds^2= -dt^2 + h_{ij}(x^{\mu}) dx^{i}dx^{j} $$
for $i,j=1,2,3$. And then we can interpret $t$ as the cosmic time, which, as I said before, is the proper time for moving along with the Hubble flow. You can then quite easily go on to show the 3-metric $h_{ij}$ can be written of the form $a(t)^2 h_{ij}(x^{k})$, and then get to the FLRW metric, but I'm being a bit sloppy and lazy with this - I assume you're only interested in the $t$ coordinate term.

If you're instead asking about why we make the assumptions in the cosmological principle, then that's a different question which I'm sure has been answered on here before.

Comment: My doubt is when we write the general form of metric $ds^2=g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu} $ but using isotropy and homogeneity we "kill" some spacial terms but the $g_{00}(x)$ term in my opinion (probably wrong) is reduced to $g_{00}(x_0)$ assuming the assumption of a global time.

Comment: @user250057 I was going to make a comment but it's too long, so I'll edit it into the answer